# Spring Tags Form Input

Tags: forms, spring, tags

i have some probelm in spring tag form input..
if i use `<form:input>`..there will be error displayed 
`java.io.IOException: JspException when evaluating the body` but if i used html tag, it's can't connect to database.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/sampling/insert"
        modelAttribute="sampling">
        <div class="form-row control-group row-fluid">
            <label class="control-label span3" name="populasi" for="normal-field">Population</label>
            <div class="controls span9">
                <form:input path="populasi" type="text" id="normal-field"
                    class="row-fluid" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row control-group row-fluid">
            <label class="control-label span3" for="normal-field">Error
                Rate</label>
            <div class="controls span9">
                <form:input path="tKesalahan" name="tKesalahan" type="text"
                    id="normal-field" class="row-fluid" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" rel="tooltip"
            data-placement="top" value="Submit" />
    </form:form>
```

Comment: please post the full exception trace

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.io.IOException: JspException when evaluating the body
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0

Comment: You import at your .jps the spring framework JSP tags library, E.g 
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

Comment: yes , i have inputed that but still got that error message

Comment: I've never used GlassFish Server, what's in its log? It seems like that it doesn't understand well JSP. Is `jsp-api.jar` in its libs?

Comment: yes, i has put     jsp-api.jar  in libs

Comment: Can you show us the full stacktrace in the glassfish log file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

name, type are not valid attributes

change the tag attributes:

```html
<form:input path="tKesalahan" id="normal-field" cssClass="row-fluid" />
```

Reference: [spring input tag attributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input)